# We're in the [same-state] as a messy tagged site

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Does anyone know how to be an expert at [same-state](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/same-state)? Who are the experts that would benefit from this tag?

Get rid of it!

Comment: On behalf of all my fellow experts who have 20+ years of experience in living in the same state as me (Maryland), I object to this request! We're being oppressed! OK, sarcasm over. Kill it with fire.